# Connection dropped by IMAP server

Tags: server, imap

I receive the following message when I try to login to squirrelmail on my ubuntu 16.04 server:

> ```
> Connection dropped by IMAP server
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when the user directories and permissions are not set correctly. In order to fix it, I used the following:

```
sudo useradd myusername
sudo passwd myusername
```

Then try sending mail by terminal mailutils to this user, so that necessary folders are made automatiacally, then continue with setting permissions:

sudo mkdir -p /var/www/html/myusername

usermod -m -d /var/www/html/myusername myusername

**Now the important part:**

sudo chown -R myusername.myusername /var/www/html/myusername

usermod -m -d /var/www/html/myusername myusername

now trick of the trade: send a mail to this user using the mailutils command:

```
root@server-name:/$ **mail myusername@**
```

...

This automatically creates a folder in /var/mail for that user and the next time you login, everything works fine.

Now, you can login. If you encounter further problems, edit the dovecot.conf file and then restart the dovecot. But I don't anticipate any problems after this.